# SQLAlchemy/SQL, how to get value in one column based on another column within a group

Tags: sqlite, group-by, sqlalchemy

I have this simple table in a sqlite database:

```
unit    groupid value
enhed1  24270   2
enhed2  24272   2
enhed3  24120   1
enhed4  24191   4
enhed4  24192   2
```

For each unit, I would like to extract the value where groupid (within group) is the lowest.

```
unit    value
enhed1  2
enhed2  2
enhed3  1
enhed4  4
```

What I have tried:

```
select(
    [
        table.c.unit,
        table.c.value
    ]
)
.where(
    table.c.groupid == select(func.min(table.c.groupid  )).group_by(table.c.unit).scalar_subquery()
)
.group_by(table.c.unit)
```

But it doesn't work, and just outputs the same value for all units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need any filtering just group_by and order:

```
select(
    [
        table.c.unit,
        table.c.value
    ]
) \
.group_by(table.c.unit) \
.order_by(table.c.unit) \
.scalar_subquery()
```

Comment: Well, that just orders the data, but doesn't extract one row pr group.

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt call scalar_subquery method